# How to make Go tests Work with Filesystem

Tags: go, testing, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing some problems testing my Go application with VsCode. This is my launch.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "type": "go",
  "request": "launch",
  "mode": "test",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test",
  "env": {},
  "args": []
}
```

Now i have the problem that my application is supposed to write files in a subfolder (atm it's ./temp). To do this i have 2 functions the first one is to determine the filepath

```golang
func getFilePath() string {
    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return dir + "/temp/ocicd-config.yaml"
}
```

and another one to Save the file

```golang
func SaveToYaml(Config Structs.Project) {
    fmt.Println("Saving Config")
    yaml, err := yaml.Marshal(Config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(yaml))
    ioutil.WriteFile(getFilePath(), yaml, 0644)
}
```

as well as to load the file

```golang
func Load() Structs.Project {
    fmt.Println("Loading Config")
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(getFilePath())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    project := Structs.Project{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(file, &project)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return project
}
```

Now the problem is that VsCode makes the application run in the ./test subfolder which makes my application try to load from and save to ./test/temp which is not what i want. I tried to change my launch.json to actually use ${workspace} as program and use "./test" as an argument but that makes the tests stop working alltogether. Now I am pretty lost. Any ideas how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Why are your tests _actually_ writing to disk? Why not create a buffer that implements a `ReadWriter` interface, and just keep it in memory instead?

Comment: For the project root I usually just set it as an environment var (e.g. `PROJECT_ROOT=$(pwd)` and then I can reference that in the code. Alternatively you can check if the dir ends in "test/" and if so go up one, though using the env var is much more foolproof.

Comment: Tests always execute with the working directory set to the directory containing the source code for that test. That's behavior of `go test` and not VSCode. The location of the test binary on the other hand is not defined (but typically the systems temporary directory). Consequently you can and should rely on relative paths in tests, if you really need the filesystem.

Comment: As an aside, [os.Executable](https://godoc.org/os#Executable) is the preferred function for getting the path to the executable.  As noted in the previous comment, use paths relative to the current working directory, not the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having tests write directly to a file on disk (potential for concurrency issues with this model), you should use a layer of abstraction on top of the filesystem (not `ioutil`).

[`github.com/spf13/afero`](https://github.com/spf13/afero) is a great library to use for this purpose. For your test cases, you can simply pass a MemFs layer instead of the OsFs (instructions [here](https://github.com/spf13/afero#step-2-declare-a-backend)).

Comment: thanks that's a good approach. just started with go after several years of type and javascript and my alternative would have been to switch to dependency injection but I'm dearly missing the default values for parameters from typescript